# How can I blend a voice recording more in with an instrumental track in Adobe Audition?

Tags: audio-recording, mastering, voice

Recently I started to record some friends singing to instrumental tracks in Adobe Audition. While the quality of both the recordings (made with Auna MIC-900S + Popkiller) and the instrumental tracks is great, it doesn't sound like they're actually a unit.

The recordings don't "blend in" with the instrumental track. It sounds like someone is singing next to me while the instrumental is playing.

What can I do in Audition to change that?

Answer (score 1):

This is basically the entire point of mixing, but the quick version is adjust the volumes so that they are closer to the level of the music, EQ their voice so that it fits better with the instruments and possibly add some light reverb to make it blend in a little better with the track.

A large part of the job of an audio engineer is to make it sound like a band rather than a bunch of individual tracks though, so this is really a very broad question and the suggestions I gave are just the tip of the iceberg in terms of what can be done.

Comment: Since it's just a hobby I am perfectly fine with "tip of the iceberg"-tips. Thank you!